# Converting PInvoke call to C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, pinvoke

My C++ DLL has function:

```
void allocate(double *&arr_not_allocated, UINT &arrayCount);
```

Normally, I pass into C++ from C# with:

```
allocate(out IntPtr arr_not_allocated, ref uint arrayCount)
```

I am just wondering what would be the equivalent call into C++ using C++/CLI instead of the above C#?

I should also note that I have no desire to hold the allocated array in managed memory(only in unmanaged), so I do not care to Marshal any structures on the managed side.
I just want to get the native pointer back from C++ and possibly pass the unmanaged array's address back to C++ in the future. So that is why I was using IntPtr in the past with P/Invoke.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; C++/CLI is essentially C++ with added features, so you'd call the C++ DLL the same way you'd call it from normal C++ code.

Comment: Sorry Im not converting the C++ code to C++/CLI.
Im just changing the call which was done from C# before.

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now. Sorry I am totally new to C++/CLI. Thank you for your comment. It really clarified things for me.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, pass by reference is completely transparent at the caller site.  It doesn't distinguish between by-reference parameters used for input, output, or both.  But it also does not permit variable declarations inside a function call, so you must declare those in advance.  Final code is quite simple:

```
double* arr_not_allocated;
UINT arrayCount = whatever;
allocate(arr_not_allocated, arrayCount);
/* now both arrayCount and arr_not_allocated have been updated by the function */
```

If you don't have an import library, you may have to use `LoadLibrary()` and pass the resulting handle to `GetProcAddress`.  The result of `GetProcAddress` gets cast to the correct function pointer type, i.e. `typedef void (*allocate_fnptr)(double*&, UINT&);`

I didn't include a calling convention, because your question didn't specify one.  But you may need to throw a `__cdecl` or `__stdcall` into the function pointer type.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea the language could use the same syntax as C++ because I kept seeing managed pointers in a lot of the code I was looking at. I guess my question was really dumb.

I am guessing that I do not need to pin the pointer or anything as long as I allocate only on the unmanaged side and do not marshal the allocated array back? In that case, I’ll just make an IntPtr from the pointer that comes back to C++/CLI and return that to C# in case I need to pass it back to C++ in the future. Thanks